# Is it possible to change any func pointer in vtable?

Tags: c++, vtable

This is an academic question. I made a macro to call and get a pointer to a virtual function through a vtable. But changing the vfunc address variable causes a memory corruption.
So it turns out that this memory area is protected from exploits?

Its classic implementation. I use GCC (MinGW) for 64 bits programs, the compiler adds a pointer to the vtable (array) of its class at the first hidden field of the object.

```
#define VTABLE_CALL(FUNC_TYPE, OBJECT, OFFSET, ...) \
    ((FUNC_TYPE)(*((size_t**)&(OBJECT))[(OFFSET)]))(__VA_ARGS__)

#define VTABLE_GET(OBJECT, OFFSET) \
    ((void*)((*(size_t**)&(OBJECT))[(OFFSET)]))

#define VTABLE_SET(OBJECT, OFFSET, NEW_FUNC_P) \
((*((size_t***)&(OBJECT))[(OFFSET)]) = (size_t*)(NEW_FUNC_P))
```

So, thats code gives SegFault

```
class A {
virtual void foo(void) { printf("Test\n"); }
};

int main()
{
    typedef void (*VMethod) (void*); // void* for "this"

    A a; // our object with first hidden vTablePtr;
    VMethod vm;

    VTABLE_CALL(VMethod, a, 0, &a); // call A::foo

    vm = (VMethod) VTABLE_GET(a, 0);
    vm(&a); // call again A::foo

    /* replace the pointer to ourselves */
    VTABLE_SET(a, 0, vm); // segmentation fault

    /* foot shot completed */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the virtual table is an implementation detail. Without more context this question cannot be answered. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @theWiseBro first sentence: "This is an academic question"

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes vptr/vtable are a artefacts, but practically all compilers use nearly the same impl strategy, at least in simple cases (i.e. no complex MI hierarchy, no virtual bases, and no covariance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vtables, like constants, are loaded and mapped read-only. A vtable is never intended to be modifiable.

To do that, you would need to change the way loading and mapping is done, possibly by changing the assembly or object code to mark the section read-write, or to do another mapping at run time after startup (I don't know if that's even doable).